# Powershell UI - DialogResult - PropertyAssignmentException

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I am creating a powershell UI for some Script.

Now I am running in an error. But first, here is my code of my form:

```
$form_appBase = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
        $form_appBase.Text = 'APP Policy creator'
        $form_appBase.Width = 350
        $form_appBase.Height = 150
        $form_appBase.AutoSize = $true

        $label_appFilename = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $label_appFilename.Location = '10,10'
        $label_appFilename.Size = '200,15'
        $label_appFilename.Text = 'Program'

        $Textbox_appFilename = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
        $Textbox_appFilename.Location = '10,30'
        $Textbox_appFilename.Size = '200,25'

        $label_appVersion = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $label_appVersion.Location = '220,10'
        $label_appVersion.Size = '100,15'
        $label_appVersion.Text = 'Version:'

        $Textbox_appVersion = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
        $Textbox_appVersion.Location = '220,30'
        $Textbox_appVersion.Size = '100,25'

        $label_appProgPath = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $label_appProgPath.Location = '10,60'
        $label_appProgPath.Size = '130,15'
        $label_appProgPath.Text = 'Path to PROG Policy'

        $textbox_appProgPath = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
        $textbox_appProgPath.Location = '150,60'
        $textbox_appProgPath.Size = '170,25'

        $Radio_appBaseSW = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
        $Radio_appBaseSW.Location = '10,90'
        $Radio_appBaseSW.Size = '100,15'
        $Radio_appBaseSW.Text = "Software"
        $Radio_appBaseSW.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::SW

        $Radio_appBaseHW = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
        $Radio_appBaseHW.Location = '10,110'
        $Radio_appBaseHW.Size = '100,15'
        $Radio_appBaseHW.Text = "Hardware"
        $Radio_appBaseHW.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::HW

        $Button_appConfirm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
        $Button_appConfirm.Location = '220,95'
        $Button_appConfirm.Size = '100,30'
        $Button_appConfirm.Text = "Create"

        $form_appBase.Controls.Add($label_appFilename)
        $form_appBase.Controls.Add($Textbox_appFilename)
        $form_appBase.Controls.Add($label_appVersion)
        $form_appBase.Controls.Add($Textbox_appVersion)
        $form_appBase.Controls.Add($label_appProgPath)
        $form_appBase.Controls.Add($textbox_appProgPath)
        $form_appBase.Controls.Add($Radio_appBaseSW)
        $form_appBase.Controls.Add($Radio_appBaseHW)
        $form_appBase.Controls.Add($Button_appConfirm)

        $form_appBase.AcceptButton = $Button_appConfirm

        $dialogResultSHW = $form_appBase.ShowDialog()

        }

        $Button_appConfirm.Add_click(
        {

        if ($dialogResultSHW -eq "SW"){$appSHW = "SW"}

        elseif ($dialogResultSHW -eq "HW"){

        $appSHW = "HW"

        $appFilename = $Textbox_appFilename.Text
        $appVersion = $Textbox_appVersion.Text
        $appProgPath = $textbox_appProgPath.Text
        $appUNCPath = "\\zen\netlogon\applocker\Output + '\' + $appSHW + '-' + $appFilename + '-' $appVersion + '.' + 'xml' "

        Write-Host "$appFilename"
        Write-Host "$appVersion"
        Write-Host "$appProgPath"
        Write-Host "$appSHW"
        Write-Host "$appUNCPath"

        powershell.exe -file \\zen\netlogon\applocker\applockerwork.ps1 -application -in $appProgPath -out $appUNCPath 
        
        }
        }
        )
```

After checking everything, I get the following error:

[Powershell_Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6gq9.png)

Can anyone help me to find out why this error persists? I tried many Ideas I found on the WWW but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Remove the lines `$Radio_appBaseSW.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::SW` . The radio button does not contain any property with this name. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobutton?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the [`[System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dialogresult) enum does not have values like `"SW"` or `"HW"`..

Remove the lines `$Radio_appBaseSW.DialogResult = ...` and `$Radio_appBaseHW.DialogResult = ...` because as [guiwhatsthat commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70798059/powershell-ui-dialogresult-propertyassignmentexception#comment125160405_70798059), the RadioButtonClass does not have such a property.

Also change `$dialogResultSHW = $form_appBase.ShowDialog()` into `[void]$form_appBase.ShowDialog()`

Then, in your `$Button_appConfirm.Add_click({..})` event, do

```
$appSHW = if ($Radio_appBaseSW.Checked) { "SW" } elseif ($Radio_appBaseHW.Checked) {"HW"}
```

and use the value of `$appSHW` do perform the different actions, or simply do

```
if ($Radio_appBaseSW.Checked) { 
    # perform action for choice Software
}
elseif ($Radio_appBaseHW.Checked) {
    perform a different action for choice Software
}
else {
    # no radiobutton was touched... Alert the user to select either the Software or the Hardware radio button
}
```

Finally, do not forget to remove the form from memory when you are done with it with `$form_appBase.Dispose()`